# Change cache storage location for individual WebBrowser control instances

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, wininet, twebbrowser

First of all, thank you all for taking time to read the question.

I am embedding Microsoft WebBrowser ActiveX control into my application. Normally such a WebBrowser instance saves cookies and caches to the system default location `C:\Users\${foo}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies`.

I want to store cookies in another directory. SFAIK that WebBrowser control uses `WinINet` to access caches and cookies. I think I should call `InternetSetOption` with a proper option flag. Can anybody shed some light on it?

Comment: not possible, use TChromium

Answer (score 1):

WinInet does not give you the option of programmably changing the paths of its storage folders.  The location of the Cookies and Cache folders are part of the calling user's profile instead.

Specifically, they are determined by the [`CSIDL_COOKIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shell folders ([`FOLDERID_Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FOLDERID_InternetCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Vista+), which are configured in the following Registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
```

Comment: Thanks. The demand is that when my WebBrowser control access Internet, cookies and caches should be stored NOT into the same location as MSIE does. If I change the registry key, MSIE will also same data to the new location, won't it?

Comment: Yes, as will any other WInInet-based or WinHTTP-based app, or any app that uses the Cookie/Cache folders directly.  you are out of luck, you CANNOT have your WebBrowser control use its own folders without affecting any other app. Find another third-party WebBrowser control that does not have that restriction.

Comment: I saw two Chinese browsers (SogouExplorer and 360 SafeBrowser), which  will manage cache/cookies/history items in individual directories. It is quite interesting, but maybe they are not WinInet based. If WinInet is a wrong way, I might should look into some other directions.

Comment: WinInet does not offer the amount of freedom you want. [EmbeddedWB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/embeddedwb/) is a common alternative for Delphi projects, for example.

Comment: EmbeddedWB is a wrapper of TWebBrowser. In other words, it has nothings specific to handle cookies stuff.